# Generate a complete build each time even for small cosmetic changes?

Tags: angular-cli

I am using Angular 12 and ng-build to generate the production build. The problem I face is sometimes there are small typos or icons that have to be updated. Once I make the small change, I end up doing a complete build of the entire application and push it to the production environment. It is taking a considerable amount of time. Is there another way to release the update without having to generate a build of the entire application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

run your application local via command # ng serve

This will allow you to quickly see UI changes without doing a full rebuild.
Note that depending on your environment setup you may not have access to the DB if using one, and if you make changes to certain core configuration files you would need to terminate the app and then rerun the command.

This will make your application available on for example http://localhost:4200, you can change the port it runs on via # ng serve --port=4203

It's what I do.